# How can i to implementate a link button in whatsapp without Bussines Manager?

Tags: url, button, whatsapp

I want to make url buttons in whatsapp but the template is very restrictive because it doesn't allow to change the url outside the bussines manager. Is it possible to do buttons like the Quick Reply but to open urls?

I try to use this template but it can't be reused, if I want to have several buttons I should create many templates for different URLs

Template url

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to create buttons in WhatsApp messages that open URLs, other than the pre-approved buttons available through the WhatsApp Business Manager.

Quick Reply buttons in WhatsApp are only able to send a pre-defined message to the recipient, and cannot be used to open URLs.

If you want to create buttons that open URLs in WhatsApp messages, you would need to use a different messaging platform or app that supports this feature. There are many such platforms available, and you can choose one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you give an example of platforms wich i can do that please?